# Intuition behind the different collapse terms of the Lindbladian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

A common way to treat *dissipative* quantum systems is through the use of the Lindblad master equation. Compared to the Schrodinger equation, it has extra non-unitary collapse/jump operators that describe coupling to the environment.

The general Lindblad evolution for a density matrix $\rho$ is given by:

$$\dot{\rho}(t)=-i \left[H(t),\rho(t)\right]+\frac{1}{2}\sum_n \left( 2C_n \rho(t) C_n^{\dagger} - \rho(t) C_n^{\dagger} C_n- C_n^{\dagger} C_n \rho(t) \right)$$

The $-i \left[H(t),\rho(t)\right]$ term is the usual unitary time evolution due to the system Hamiltonian $H$. The rest of the terms describe wavefunction "collapse" via non-unitary collapse operators $C_n$, $C_n^{\dagger}$. Roughly speaking, the action of the $C_n$ operator is to take an arbitrary initial state and work to project it to the non-zero eigenvectors of $C_n$. An example use for $C_n$ would be for describing the spontaneous decay of atomic levels to the ground state, which for a two-level system has the general form $$C=\sqrt{\Gamma}\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$$

Where C$ represents the decay from $\vert 1\rangle \rightarrow \vert 0\rangle$ and $\Gamma$ would the decay rate.

My question is: **Can the individual contribution of each collapse term be connected to an intuitive physical behavior?** Specifically, what do each of the following terms individually correspond to, and how should one visualize/intuit them?

1. $C_n \rho(t) C_n^{\dagger}$
2. $\rho(t) C_n C_n^{\dagger}$
3. $C_n C_n^{\dagger}\rho(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the equation in the following way:
$$
\dot{\rho}(t) =
\hat{\mathcal{L}}_0\rho + \hat{\mathcal{L}}_{\textrm{J}}\rho
=
-i\left(H_{\textrm{eff}}(t)\rho(t) - \rho(t)H^{\dagger}_{\textrm{eff}}(t)\right)
+ \sum_n C_n \rho(t) C_n^{\dagger}\,,
$$
where
$$
H_{\textrm{eff}}(t) = H(t) - i C_n^{\dagger}C_n\,,
$$
is an effective non-Hermitian Hamiltonian.  As I'll show below, in this form, we can interpret the time-evolution in the following way.  The "free" time-evolution governed by the first term corresponds to the standard unitary time-evolution due to the system Hamiltonian combined with an effective *decay* evolution "out of" the "current" state.  Then, the second term is the *jump* term, controlling the quantum jumps into different channels.

---

For convenience, in what follows, we'll assume that $H(t)$ is time-independent.

To see how this interpretation works, let's move into an interaction picture by defining
$$
\tilde{\rho}(t) = e^{-\mathcal{L}_0t}\rho(t)e^{\mathcal{L}_0t}\,,
$$
in which case the master equation becomes
$$
\frac{d\tilde{\rho}}{dt}=
e^{-\mathcal{L}_0t}
\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{\textrm{J}}
e^{\mathcal{L}_0t}
\tilde{\rho}\,.
$$
Integrating this equation and plugging it into itself an infinite number of times yields a Dyson-like series, given by
\begin{align}
\tilde{\rho}(t)=
\tilde{\rho}\left( t_{0}\right) +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{n}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{n}}dt_{n-1}\cdots
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{3}}dt_{2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{2}}dt_{1}
e^{-\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}t_{n}}\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{J}e^{\hat{%
\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t_{n}-t_{n-1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{J}\cdots 
\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{J}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t_{2}-t_{1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{J}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}t_{1}}\tilde{\rho}\left(
t_{0}\right)\,,
\end{align}
and after moving out of the interaction picture, it becomes
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}\left( t\right) &=e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t-t_{0}\right) }%
\hat{\rho}\left( t_{0}\right) +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sum_{j_{1},\dots
,j_{n}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt_{n}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{n}}dt_{n-1}\cdots
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{3}}dt_{2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{2}}dt_{1}\\
&\quad\quad\mbox{}\times e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t-t_{n}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}%
_{j_{n}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t_{n}-t_{n-1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}%
}_{j_{n-1}}\cdots \hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{2}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(
t_{2}-t_{1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{1}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(
t_{1}-t_{0}\right) }\hat{\rho}\left( t_{0}\right)\,.
\end{align}
The very first term represents the "free" time-evolution according to the effective Hamiltonian. We can interpret each other term in the following way.

Consider the expression inside all the integrals, given by
$$
e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t-t_{n}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}%
_{j_{n}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left( t_{n}-t_{n-1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}%
}_{j_{n-1}}\cdots \hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{2}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(
t_{2}-t_{1}\right) }\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{1}}e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(
t_{1}-t_{0}\right) }\hat{\rho}\left( t_{0}\right)\,.
$$
We can see that we start with the density operator at the initial time $t_0$ and then evolve according to the free evolution until time $t_1$ via $e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(t_{1}-t_{0}\right) }$.  At this point, we apply the jump operator $\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{1}}$, which corresponds to the action
$$
\rho(t_1)\to C_{j_1}\rho(t_1)C_{j_1}^{\dagger}\,.
$$
We then evolve the density matrix from here via the free evolution until time $t_1$ (via $e^{\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{0}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right) }$), at which point we apply the jump operator $\hat{\mathcal{L}}_{j_{2}}$. We continue this until we get to time $t$.

This evolution is called a *quantum trajectory*, and it is *not* a solution to the master equation.  To get that, we have to (incoherently) sum over all the different ways that this can happen.  This is why there is the outer sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$, which is a sum over the *number* of quantum jumps that occur in the time interval $[t_0,t]$, and this is why there are the (nested) integrals, which essentially are there to sum over all the possible *times* at which the jumps can occur.

---

To see this all a little more clearly, we can assume that the initial state is a pure state, i.e.,
$$
\rho(t_0) = |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i |\,.
$$
It is relatively straightforward to see that the actions of both the free-evolution operator and of the individual jump operators preserve the purity of the state. Then, the free time-evolution is just given by
$$
|\psi(t_{n})\rangle =  e^{-iH_{\textrm{eff}}(t_n-t_{n-1})}|\psi(t_{n-1})\rangle\,,
$$
and the action of the jump operators is just
$$
|\psi(t_{n-1})\rangle\to C_n|\psi(t_{n-1})\rangle\,.
$$
It is only after we incoherently sum over the different possible numbers of jumps and times at which the jumps occur that the state necessarily becomes a density matrix.

Finally, we note the following. The eigenvalues of the effective Hamiltonian necessarily have non-positive imaginary parts, because the operator $C^{\dagger}C$ is manifestly a positive operator (so its eigenvalues are real and non-negative). Thus, the eigenvalues of the free-evolution operator $e^{-iH_{\textrm{eff}}t}$ are necessarily of the form $e^{i\alpha t - \gamma t}$, where $\gamma > 0$.  Thus, the free evolution corresponds to a *decay* "away" from the initial state, indicating that the probability of a quantum jump *out* of the state is increasing with time.  Indeed, without going through the details, the math shows that the cumulative probability that *no* jumps occur in the time interval $[t_0,t]$ is given by $1 - \langle \psi(t) | \psi(t) \rangle$, indicating that the probability of a jump occurring will generally increase in time, since the $e^{-\gamma t}$ factor will guarantee that the norm of a pure state will generally decrease over time.

---

For much more detail, see papers about the quantum Monte Carlo jump approach in quantum optics. One good reference is a [review article by Plenio and Knight](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.70.101).

Comment: This was very helpful. What do you get if you just ignore the "jump" terms and just keep non-unitary evolution with $H_{eff}$? Is there some regime where that sort of treatment is useful?

Comment: To clarify, the naive construction would be to just have a Hamiltonian that looks like your $H_{eff}$, but that is missing out the physics that's going on here?

Comment: @KFGauss The problem with $H_{\textrm{eff}}$ is that it is non-Hermitian; you need the jump term to conserve probability.  The idea is that the probability decay caused by the effective Hamiltonian corresponding to the growing probability that a jump should occur. As far as I know, it's not generally useful to keep just that term.